# includes not working

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, jquery-mobile, include

I built a jquerymobile website (/mobile/) on my host and it works great. Moved it to the client's host and it's not loading, just see a grey loading circle in the middle.

I'm using includes on the websites and for my host had to add these lines to the .htaccess file to make it work:

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml .html .txt
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
```

this is the line for the header include, which i think is causing the loading problem on the client's host:

```
<!--#include file="header.txt" -->
```

currently the .htaccess on the client's host has this:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .html .htm .txt
```

when i changed it to this:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .html .htm .txt
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
```

it caused an "Internal Server Error" on the main site and the mobile, so i changed it back.

i removed the includes and added the regular html and it works fine on the client's host, so the includes is definitely the problem, but i'd like to keep the includes.

Any ideas on what i could do to allow the includes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

solved it. just changed the syntax:

```
<!--#include file="header.txt" -->
```

to

```
<?php include 'header.txt'; ?>
```

and all works fine.